# Provide contextvars.Context with a ContextManager

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, contextmanager, python-contextvars

I'm trying to manage transactions in my DB framework (I use MongoDB with umongo over pymongo).

To use transaction, one must pass a `session` kwarg along the whole call chain. I would like to provide a context manager that would isolate the transaction. Only the function at the end of the call chain would need to be aware of the `session` object.

I found out about context variables and I'm close to something but not totally there.

What I would like to have:

```py
with Transaction():
    # Do stuff
    d = MyDocument.find_one()
    d.attr = 12
    d.commit()
```

Here's what I came up with for now:

```py
s = ContextVar('session', default=None)

class Transaction(AbstractContextManager):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ctx = copy_context()
        # Create a new DB session
        session = db.create_session()
        # Set session in context
        self.ctx.run(s.set, session)

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    # Adding a run method for convenience
    def run(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ctx.run(func, *args, **kwargs)

def func():
    d = MyDocument.find_one()
    d.attr = 12
    d.commit()

with Transaction() as t:
    t.run(func)
```

But I don't have the nice context manager syntax. The point of the context manager would be so say "everyting that's in there should be run in that context".

What I wrote above is not really better than just using a function:

```py
def run_transaction(func, *args, **kwargs):
    ctx = copy_context()
    session = 12
    ctx.run(s.set, session)
    ctx.run(func)

run_transaction(func)
```

Am I on the wrong track?

Am I misusing context variables?

Any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

---

**Basically, I'd like to be able to open a context like a context manager**

```py
session = ContextVar('session', default=None)

with copy_context() as ctx:
    session = db.create_session()
    # Do stuff
    d = MyDocument.find_one()
    d.attr = 12
    d.commit()
```

I'd embed this in a `Transaction` context manager to manage the session stuff and only keep operations on `d` in user code.

Comment: Jerome did you find the time to test this ?
What final approach did you apply ?

Comment: I never went further but I think the accepted answer is the right (and nice) way.

Comment: I opened a pull request with CPython to add context manager support:  https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/99634

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a contextmanager to create the session and transaction and store the session in the ContextVar for use by other functions.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from contextvars import ContextVar
import argparse
import pymongo


SESSION = ContextVar("session", default=None)


@contextmanager
def transaction(client):
    with client.start_session() as session:
        with session.start_transaction():
            t = SESSION.set(session)
            try:
                yield
            finally:
                SESSION.reset(t)


def insert1(client):
    client.test.txtest1.insert_one({"data": "insert1"}, session=SESSION.get())


def insert2(client):
    client.test.txtest2.insert_one({"data": "insert2"}, session=SESSION.get())


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--url", default="mongodb://localhost:27017")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    client = pymongo.MongoClient(args.url)

    # Create and lear collections, collections must be created outside the transaction
    insert1(client)
    client.test.txtest1.delete_many({})
    insert2(client)
    client.test.txtest2.delete_many({})

    with transaction(client):
        insert1(client)
        insert2(client)

    for doc in client.test.txtest1.find({}):
        print(doc)
    for doc in client.test.txtest2.find({}):
        print(doc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Don't you need to use `copy_context` and `run` at some point?

Comment: No, not unless you are doing something advanced and managing all this manually. `asyncio` and `futures` and so on all use `copy_context` and `run` as needed internally so that you don't need to.

Comment: I guess I was overthinking it, then. I'll come back to upvote/accept once I get the time to try that. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get the time to try it but reading it now with a better understanding it makes total sense. Accepting this answer. Thanks.